# Commit exceeds GitHub's file size limit - no big file

Tags: git, github

Heres is the error i'm getting:

```
$ git push origin projectBranch
Counting objects: 2083, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1036/1036), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1592/1592), 3.94 MiB | 33.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 1592 (delta 855), reused 1003 (delta 366)
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected.
remote: error: Trace: bf52326a68b9d603afbfda5f771f88ca
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File test is 512.00 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100 MB
To git@github.com:vendor/project.git
! [remote rejected] projectBranch -> projectBranch (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:vendor/project.git'
```

But as you can see theres no big file originating the problem - excepting git .packs files:

```
 find . -type f -size +10000k -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{ print $9 ": " $5 }'
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-758ec92fb124f88efbb6e9f8076703796077a358.pack: 20M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-f0b6555fca6ab942ac43d49f7e449c8ec09f3782.pack: 20M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-e9f9c4b63a6384c52baea6371d6ac1298f53c872.pack: 20M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-eb21336f15f1ace62243f17968ed4d9483335b75.pack: 20M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-557e43170409bcefbae895fe738ebfcc75be5952.pack: 20M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-7338c43b5e21b37f128ff8583ac73fb7876468cc.pack: 20M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-d833d9897997d7f66f90590b4b519bb911df327c.pack: 20M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-562e0d3921f82b886f1134b18e027d82a57ac692.pack: 17M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-e88f92e7c83a7b4c15b43b766bc086bdf3798758.pack: 20M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-cbd324f1b2d7ab7e5ddd265ca2972026000eacfe.pack: 20M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-b4bb35ebec17d36a6e1068a3d0d84f0f6ddae447.pack: 20M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-fa5b22cfe500b00d5b241ac0de733dd6bed6a2e0.pack: 20M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-5b1d3e100e3eb210028390378693839250d32fae.pack: 20M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-023025b735c3ff968469a6d588b71100e529243e.pack: 18M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-7a63ccdbda3f45d3289ca7705bbc8436b0e2cc65.pack: 20M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-147a4853500759300e20897c4db9520851f80d6d.pack: 20M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-c9b56efb8f6071e27e0d1c426b7b6949e79086ff.pack: 16M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-b3740f737873672773059dac6bffdbae92b911d6.pack: 20M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-18b33125b850e3860a054c53226c49cd941118e6.pack: 17M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-ba3b220cab86a2c16045df1d051cc99150eb2721.pack: 20M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-895f46d7aebf282c244e8daec53e24d6807b2d03.pack: 18M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-4f3a34d283d3e34f7cb0a1362b0f56ca9d514406.pack: 18M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-bdad2215456a72fc736b02180a448d3cd865a88a.pack: 20M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-79954a5a15243696fe5cd938242fe3c3b39a0d9a.pack: 20M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-879640c488ef0e3f1c5211f3835f7389fecd5376.pack: 20M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-4f113afe1504ce0da8ddd4aac102485abd7d87e5.pack: 20M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-14af859c1f13f341ebf2f796f55d1c22af377656.pack: 20M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-5ec169224c985f08f961b90761d6efe6fc8ac63a.pack: 20M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-afd1ea8411e614883aaf24434d49f7c0cf38283c.pack: 20M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-fe5bd07284551f3bf8c4de69014d2c0a67da73df.pack: 20M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-fe65927c72b4d09f8dab40e50daa8dd113eabd01.pack: 17M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-118900d2804a291bf360c12e9301770a44a854c6.pack: 20M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-ddc8bce1658000cca28952c8e5b160797e3a6193.pack: 19M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-0cf98e48845c137e0abf14ef1802aa2996894c13.pack: 20M
 ./.git/objects/pack/pack-e734c5f16b5d9cebf217302bd03c105f67c362b6.pack: 19M
```

I already tried spliting the package, because of this theres's so much .pack files. Tried [this](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files) too but, as you can see, there no big file.

Comment: I solved the trick by searching for large files on the history with [this][1] bash.

Then I removed the files it found with:
    git filter-branch --force --index-filter   'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch FILENAME'   --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all



  [1]: https://github.com/jeanCarloMachado/personalScripts/blob/master/git-list-large

Comment: You should add that as an answer to your own question.